# Java - while loop not working as expected

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean

I am working with a fairly basic programming task in Java. We are asked to create a chat-robot, where the robot is to answer randomly from a set of given strings until the user writes "Bye!", where the robot will simply reply with "Bye!" and end the program. I've written the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Robot {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random random = new Random();

    String[] answer = new String[6];
    answer[0] = "blabla1";
    answer[1] = "blabla2";
    answer[2] = "blabla3";
    answer[3] = "blabla4";
    answer[4] = "blabla5";
    answer[5] = "blabla6";
    boolean keepGoing = true;


    System.out.println("Hello, how can I help you?");
    while (keepGoing) {
        String input = in.next();
        int output = random.nextInt(6);
        System.out.println(answer[output]);

        if (input.equals("Bye!")){
            keepGoing = false;
            System.out.println("Bye!");
        }

    } 

}
```

I have two issues with the program:

1. At times, seemingly at random, the program will answer with multiple strings.
2. When writing "Bye!", the program throws in another string before writing "Bye!". I do know that this may be resolved by adding "break;", but I'd consider this bad practice seeing as I am already using a boolean. (I'd like to keep using it.)

I have no idea as to why these errors occur.

Comment: Does that code even compiles?

Comment: `continue` is a reserved word in java and should not be used as a variable.  Also, you use the variable `fortsett` in your loop and it isn't even defined.  Pretty sure that the code will not even compile as-is.

Comment: `continue` should be `fortsett`

Comment: Didn't you notice weird colors there?

Comment: You also don't use BBcode here; just indent the code four spaces.

Comment: @RohitJain, yes, it compiles.

Comment: @jgm, translating error.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I do not understand the question.

Comment: @jgm, the word continue is not used in the original program, it is translated from Norwegian.

Comment: If you don't want to print a sentence when input is "Bye!" then add a else-case and print only when the input is not "Bye!". That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the condition for exit before printing anything. That will resolve the 2nd issue

```
while (true) {
    String input = in.next();

    if (input.equals("Bye!")){
        System.out.println("Bye!"); 
        break;           
    }
    int output = random.nextInt(6);
    System.out.println(answer[output]);
 }
```

Comment: continue? are you sur?

Comment: 1. Your coding style is not consistent. 2. You don't need an extra boolean to stop the loop. Use break; when you want to stop the loop. That's why it exists. So: "while(;;)" and "break;" for stopping.

Comment: @zmirc: You mean `for(;;){}` and `while(true){}`!

Answer (score 1):

Change your program like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Robot {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random random = new Random();

    String[] answer = new String[6];
    answer[0] = "blabla1";
    answer[1] = "blabla2";
    answer[2] = "blabla3";
    answer[3] = "blabla4";
    answer[4] = "blabla5";
    answer[5] = "blabla6";
    boolean continue1 = true;


    System.out.println("Hello, how can I help you?");
    while (continue1) {
        String input = in.next();
        int output = random.nextInt(6);
       if (input.equals("Bye!")){
        continue1 = false;
            System.out.println("Bye!");
        }else
        {
             System.out.println(answer[output]);
        }

    } 

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code snappet to solve Issue2:

```
    while (keepGoing) {
        String input = in.next();
        int output = random.nextInt(6);
        if(!input.equals("Bye!"))
            System.out.println(answer[output]);

        if (input.equals("Bye!")){
            keepGoing = false;
            System.out.println("Bye!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random random = new Random();

    String[] answer = new String[6];
    answer[0] = "blabla1";
    answer[1] = "blabla2";
    answer[2] = "blabla3";
    answer[3] = "blabla4";
    answer[4] = "blabla5";
    answer[5] = "blabla6";
    boolean keepGoing = true;

    System.out.println("Hello, how can I help you?");
    while (keepGoing) {
        String input = in.next();
        if ("Bye!".equals(input)) {
            keepGoing = false;
            System.out.println("Bye!");
        } else {
            int output = random.nextInt(6);
            System.out.println(answer[output]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Robot 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            Random random = new Random();

            String[] answer = new String[6];
            answer[0] = "blabla1";
            answer[1] = "blabla2";
            answer[2] = "blabla3";
            answer[3] = "blabla4";
            answer[4] = "blabla5";
            answer[5] = "blabla6";
            boolean keepGoing = true;


            System.out.println("Hello, how can I help you?");
            while (keepGoing) 
            {
                String input = in.next();
                int output = random.nextInt(6);
                System.out.println(answer[output]);

                if (input.equals("Bye!"))
                {
                        keepGoing = false;
                        System.out.println("Bye!");
                } //This bracket is the only thing missing in your code.
            }// End of while loop

        } // End of main method

}// End of class
```